# How to sum amounts from one collection and update a field in another collection by using an array of ids?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Foolishly I have agreed to build a website for a fantasy Formula One competition that we're running at work.

I'm new to mongobd and I'm stuck on how to update the total points each player has based on the accumulative points of the selection of drivers each player has chosen.

I have two collections: players and drivers. `driver_selection` in players is an array of driver ids. How can I use this to update the `total_points` field by summing up the `driver_points` fields in the driver collection?

```
  // Example player document from players collection
  {
      id: 1,
      player_name: "Tom",
      total_points: 0,
      driver_selection: [1, 4, 44]
  }
  
  // Driver collection
  {
      id: 1,
      driver_name: "Max Verstappen",
      driver_points: 200.
  }
  {
      id: 4,
      driver_name: "Lando Norris",
      driver_points: 150.
  }
  {
      id: 44,
      driver_name: "Lewis Hamilton",
      driver_points: 100.
  }
```

I have tried using `$unwind` on the `driver_selection` then `$lookup` from the drivers collection with id as the foreign field. Finally I'm grouping by id and using `$sum` on the `$points` field.
However points always comes back as 0.

```
    db.players.aggregate([
    {
      $unwind: "$driver_selection"
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        "from": "drivers",
        "localField": "driver_selection",
        "foreignField": "id",
        "as": "result"
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        "_id": "$id",
        "points": {
          $sum: "$points"
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `$lookup` with `$sum`:

```
db.players.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "drivers",
      localField: "driver_selection",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "total_points",
      pipeline: [{$project: {driver_points: 1, _id: 0}}]
  }},
  {$set: {total_points: {$sum: "$total_points.driver_points"}}},
  {$merge: {into: "players"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7Q-bI69yvWL)

`$unwind` is considered as a costly operation and there is no need to use it here. `$lookup` can work on an array, and it is even easier to `$sum` up.

The pipeline allows you to bring only the data you need from the other collection.

**EDIT**:

Added the last `$merge` step to update the collection.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need except I want to update the existing points field for each player in the players collection.

Comment: @Mark McNaughton, Updated accordingly.

Comment: This works nicely. I added a further project stage so that only the points get merged into players. Thanks you.
Now I just need to work out how to do this with Mongoose lol